# Insert/Update values in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

What would be the best way to Insert/Update the values in a Grid view
on clicking a save button placed somewhere.
in the page .
I dont want that to be done like Using Insert Item template and EditItemTemplate.

**My thought:**
"Loop through each row of Gridview and 
connecting to database and 
execute the command
and close the connection."

Or is there any way so that we can connect to database only once and perform 
Insert/Update operations.

any suggestions would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you use `DataSet` or `DataTable`? and then bind the `DataTable`|`DataSet` to your gridview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May these articles help you:

- [Bulk Edit with GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/BulkEditGridView.aspx)
- [Edit Update Multiple Records/Rows In Gridview With Checkbox ASP.NET](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/edit-multiple-records-gridview-checkbox.html)

There are many other related articles:

- [Editable GridView in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Editable_GridView.aspx)
- [ASP.NET GridView - Add a new record](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/addupdate.aspx)
- [Insert, Update, Delete with Gridview....simple way](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/InsertingWithGridView.aspx)